# Make a request in react js got undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want t make a http request like this:

```js
 const fun = (params) => {
    fetch(`${params.url}`, {
        method: "get",
        mode: 'cors', 
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            ...params.headers,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(params.body)
    })
        .then((response) => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
            return data
        }).catch(err => {
        return Promise.reject(err);
    });
};



console.log(fun({
  url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
}))
```

Why i get `undefined` and what should change to make the code workable?

Comment: you're not returning  anything from `fun` function

Comment: @Naren, i am working with javascript not java

Comment: You can return the `fetch().then(response => response.json())` Promise and then use `.then((data) => {// stuff with data})` on the returned promise after calling your function

Comment: That's typo link mistake,

Comment: @AskMen your still not returning anything from fun,